# Create a Regex pattern to validate this example expression (.1);

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for some help in validating that this string is valid.  I need a regex pattern that will catch any letters within the set of parenthesis. I also need to make sure there is a semi-colon at the end of the parentheses.  Any ideas?  My regex is absolutely terrible......

This is what I want to match:

```
Total Hours Worked (.5);
Total Hours Worked (.A);
Total Hours Worked (A);
```

First result should be false while the last 2 should be true.

This is what I have tried:

```
Match validateLettersAndSemiColon = Regex.Match(StringToMatch, "[a-z]);");
```

Comment: Could you please add example strings, expected outcome and the language you're using? Your description is quite difficult to understand

Comment: in which language? is it java?

Comment: C# and an example would be: Total Hours Worked (.5);

Comment: and what is your desired output?

Comment: "catch any letters within the set of parenthesis." As far as I can see, there are no letters within the parens... only a period and a number.

Comment: I was looking for the Match != Success.

Comment: Jerry I updated a bad expression in which I wish to catch.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Aaron you want to validate if the string `Total Hours Worked (.5);` contains letters inside the parenthesis or not and ends with a semi-colon?

Comment: And have you tried anything so far? post your code.

Comment: Match validateLettersAndSemiColon = Regex.Match(StringToMatch, "[a-z]);");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an example using as input the following 3 strings:

```
Total Hours Worked (.5);
Total Hours Worked (.A);
Total Hours Worked (A);
```

I am not considering any nested inner parenthesis only that the possible combinations inside the parenthesis are letters and dot.

Here is a simple example:

```
string[] data = new string[] { "Total Hours Worked (.5);", "Total Hours Worked (.A);", "Total Hours Worked (A);" };
foreach (string input in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Result for:" + input);
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"\([a-z.]+\);$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("YES");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NO");
    }
}
```

`@"\([a-z.]+\);$"` the `\` before the parenthesis escapes it to be captured as a normal parenthesis, the `[a-z.]+` means we want to match any amount of letters and dot, can also limit it but should give you an idea. The `$` at the end means we want it to end with `);`

If you want to limit it to a single dot right after the first parenthesis you may use the below regex instead, it will turn the dot as a single optional character at the begin right after the `(`

```
@"\(\.?[a-z]+\);$"
```

The result of the above would be:

```
Total Hours Worked (.5);
NO
Total Hours Worked (.A);
YES
Total Hours Worked (A);
YES
```

Comment: One thing - May not be an issue, but just want to point it out, this would also match `(A.);` or even `(.);` as TRUE. Again, I don't know if this would be an issue, but it will accept any letter or a "." in any position within the parentheses as correct...

Comment: above, there is also a second regex that will match the letter with and without the dot coming right after the `(`, right below the regex explanation.

Comment: Awesome, Sorry, I looked at the code and should have read further... Awesome explanation too!!! +1

Comment: :) Glad you liked it, I am not very good at explaining regex, look away.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is `/\([^)]+\);/` or `/\(.+?\)/` if you don't have nested parenthesis. It works even if you have two or more of these parenthesis group in the same line.

If you have nested parenthesis use `/\(.+\);/`, but this will not work if you have two or more parenthesis group in the same line.

In the end, if you have a string like:

```
 (aba(cc);a);eeee(dd(e););
```

can be pretty hard for a single regex.

**Edit 1**

If your parenthesis group you want to validate takes the whole string, you can use a `^` to signal the beginning of the string and a `$` for the end. Thus the regex becomes

```
 /^\([^)]+\);$/
```

Comment: Thanks Davide I would even consider breaking this out into 2 regex expressions.  Which would prob make it easier.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: I would use two regex only for dealing with nested parenthesis, but it seems to me you don't need it here. You can use a character class like `[A-Za-z0-9.]` instead of the `[^)]` if you that only letters, numbers and the dot should appear.

Answer (score 1):

Try following regex:

```
\([^0-9]+\)\s*;
```

This will match any characters within parenthesis except digits.

I would recommend to put `\s*` between `)` and `;` to allow space as in most of the programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
        string[] inputstrings = new string[] { "Total Hours Worked (.5);", "Total Hours Worked (.A);", "Total Hours Worked (A);" };//Collection of inputs.
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\(\.?(?<StringValue>[a-zA-Z]*)\)\;{1}");//Regular expression to find all matches.
        foreach (string input in inputstrings)//Iterate through each string in collection.
        {
            Match match = rgx.Match(input);
            if (match.Success)//If a match is found.
            {
                string value = match.Groups[1].Value;//Capture first named group.
                Console.WriteLine(value);//Display captured substring.
            }
            else//If nothing is found.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A match was not found.");
            }
        }
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/Y1lEuS) is Ideone sample.